# Modi diversi per chiamare gli imperatori

Tags: word-choice

Qualcuno sa (con fonti, ovviamente) come mai in italiano usiamo i nomi locali per indicare gli imperatori austriaco o tedesco (*Kaiser*, che deriva da “Caesar”), russo (*Zar*, idem) e qualche volta etiope (*negus*, ma che in realtà se non erro significa “re”), ma non per esempio per quelli britannico, francese, giapponese, dell'antica Roma o di Bisanzio, per menzionare solo quelli di cui si parla di più?

Comment: In sostanza, perché termini come Zar, Kaiser e, anche se meno comune, Negus sono entrati nella lingua italiana?

Comment: In Francia si parla più spesso di re piuttosto che di imperatori. Napoleone passa alla storia come Napoleone, senza bisogno del titolo di imperatore.  Ma il Re Sole è conosciuto, anche da noi come le Rois Soleil. Il Giappone è troppo lontano e la sua storia non è molto conosciuta, almeno in Italia.

Comment: In sostanza penso che dipenda dalla vicinanza e dalla rilevanza storica nei nostri confronti.

Comment: D'impulso, senza nulla a sostenermi, direi che "kaiser" e "zar" sono entrati nel dizionario e nell'uso comune perché, etimologia a parte, vengono avvertiti come diversi dall'italiano; "kaiser" e "negus" poi anche per ragioni storiche. Altri invece, come "emperor" ed "empereur", difficoltà di pronuncia a parte, suonano simili all'"imperatore" italiano e come tali traducibili, adattabili o sostituibili con le parole che già possediamo.

Comment: La mia impressione è che *Kaiser* non sia stato molto usato per gli imperatori della casa d'Asburgo (prima del Sacro Romano Impero, poi d'Austria), mentre lo era per il Kaiser del Reich tedesco (dopo il 1870).

Comment: Può darsi, @egreg, tanto che il GDLI lo definisce “Imperatore di Germania” e dice che per antonomasia si riferisce a Guglielmo II, ma poi segue un esempio dal Carducci in cui parla di milanesi fatte bastonare dal Kaiser, e quindi sembra che parli di quello austriaco.

Comment: @egreg: ...o no? Qualcuno sa per caso a quale episodio facesse riferimento Carducci? http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/8?seq=647

Comment: @DaG Per quello che può valere, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kaiser&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3 mostra un chiaro picco dopo il 1870.

Comment: @egreg - con il case sensitive lo scenario cambia: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kaiser+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

Comment: @Hachi Il picco per “Kaiser” è nel 1915-16, molto comprensibilmente.

Comment: Giusto, @egreg, non avevo pensato a guardare i ngrams. Ma in effetti il picco è un po' prima, specie se lo si guarda senza “smoothing”, verso metà degli anni '60 dell'800. D'altro canto, guardando al volo un po' di esempi, c'è una macedonia di testi in tedesco e, in quelli in italiano, vari riferimenti a una nave, che penso sia questa: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_Kaiser_(1858), che partecipò alla battaglia di Lissa, appunto del 1866.

Comment: Attento, @Hachi, quello che stai linkando è relativo al corpus in lingua inglese.

Comment: @DaG    si, quello italiano non è molto diverso...non ho fatto a tempo a cambiarlo.

Comment: Mikado, o secondo la Treccani anche 'tenno', sono altri termini utilizzati, in italiano, per indicare l'imperatore del Giapppone https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mikado. Gli stessi termini si possono trovare anche nei dizionari inglesi, https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tenno

Comment: Credo che ci sia anche da considerare la necessità di indicare qualcuno che, agli occhi dei governi o abitanti di altri paesi, sarebbe potuto, a seconda dell'epoca, non apparire come un 'imperatore' vero e proprio in quanto a capo di un territorio piuttosto omogeneo (nonostante la vastità del territorio Russo). Lo stesso discorso potrebbe valere in epoca moderna per l'imperatore giapponese, ma in questo caso ci sono considerazioni storiche e religiose.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda 'negus', posso immaginare che il termine sia divenuto popolare con la guerra d'Etiopia e sia diventato d'uso comune tanto per brevità, quanto per le considerazioni territoriali del mio commento precedente. Credo sia possibile che ci sia stata anche un'intenzione di indicare, con il termine 'negus', una figura in qualche modo esotica, con riverberi biblici, alle volte anche con con una connotazione negativa nell'uso italiano dell'epoca, per es. "Alla satrapia del Negus si dovrà sostituirne un’altra" (Montanelli)

Comment: Piccolo appunto a margine: il monarca inglese non è mai chiamato imperatore, neanche in lingua originale. Victoria era sì imperatrice, ma imperatrice d'India (usando una traduzione dubbiosa del titolo originale del Moghul, essentialmente perché Victoria voleva essere chiamata *Empress*)

Comment: Infatti, @DenisNardin, mi riferivo a quando esisteva l'impero britannico. Adesso anche il capo di stato tedesco o austriaco non viene chiamato “imperatore”. :) Quello giapponese per ora sì. Putin non so. Comunque, ammetto che non avevo presente che tecnicamente il titolo si riferiva solo all'India.